# How can numba implementation of str.find() be slower, than the pure python one?

Tags: python, numba

How can it be, that pure python code of  str.find() is faster, than its numba implementation?
numba==0.48.0 (0.49.0 cannot be loaded, seems buggy)

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit,njit

def search_match(a,search,n):
   for z in range(n):
      i = a.find(search)
   return i

@njit
def search_match_jit(a,search,n):
   for z in range(n):
      i = a.find(search)
   return i

n = 10000000
a  = '.56485.36853.32153.65646.34763.23152.11321.65886.54975.12781.'
search = '2315'

print('Str.find:')
start = timer()
i = search_match(a,search,n)
print(timer() - start)

i = search_match_jit(a,search,1) # precompile
print('Jit:')
start = timer()
i = search_match_jit(a,search,n)
print(timer() - start)
```

Comment: JIT compilation has a significant amount of overhead, but offers performance improvements on large data sets / high call volume. I expect if you significantly increase those you'll begin to see performance returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in CPython implementation of `str.find` is not "pure Python" - it's already written in C: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/find.h

This is not the kind of thing that we'd expect Numba to speed up. Indeed, since Numba has other complications to deal with, it's not surprising that it's a little slower. See the following "warning" in the [Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html), where I'm bolding the last sentence for emphasis:

> The performance of some operations is known to be slower than the CPython implementation. These include substring search (`in`, `.contains()` and `find()`) and string creation (like `.split()`). Improving the string performance is an ongoing task, but the speed of CPython is unlikely to be surpassed for basic string operation in isolation. **Numba is most successfully used for larger algorithms that happen to involve strings, where basic string operations are not the bottleneck.**

Basically, the Numba developers added string methods to nopython mode so that it would be easier for users, who might have a few lines of code that happen to involve strings mixed in with heavy-duty numerical code, to compile their code without any redesign. But Numba isn't intended to speed up the string code: its goal is the heavy-duty numerical stuff, and the string support is just for convenience.